# Displaying multiple row values in one row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

This query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    PT.PRODUCT AS PRODUCT, PT.TEXT_CODE AS TEXT_CODE, 
    PHT.PHRASE AS F_PHRASE
FROM 
    PRODUCT_TEXT PT
LEFT JOIN 
    PHRASE_LINK PHL ON PT.TEXT_CODE = PHL.TEXT_CODE
INNER JOIN 
    PHRASE_TRANSLATIONS PHT ON PHL.PHRASE_ID = PHT.PHRASE_ID
WHERE 
    PT.DATA_CODE = 'MANU' AND PHT.LANGUAGE = 'EN'

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT
    PT.F_ALIAS AS PRODUCT, PT.TEXT_CODE AS TEXT_CODE, 
    PHT.PHRASE AS F_PHRASE
FROM 
    PROD_ALIAS_TEXT PT
LEFT JOIN 
    PHRASE_LINK PHL ON PT.TEXT_CODE = PHL.TEXT_CODE
INNER JOIN 
    PHRASE_TRANSLATIONS PHT ON PHL.PHRASE_ID = PHT.PHRASE_ID
WHERE 
    PT.DATA_CODE = 'MANU' AND PHT.LANGUAGE = 'EN'
```

returns this output:

```
F_PRODUCT       F_TEXTCODE       F_PHRASE 
-----------------------------------------------------
A               MANU001          TEST1      
A               MANU002          TEST2      
B               MANU003          XYZ
C               MANU001          ABC
C               MANU005          DEF
```

Now I want to concatenate the `F_PHRASE` into a single row for the products which contains more then one `F_TEXTCODE`. Not for all the products.

Sample desired output:

```
F_PRODUCT       F_TEXTCODE              F_PHRASE 
-----------------------------------------------------
A               MANU001,MANU002          TEST1,TEST2      
B               MANU003                  XYZ
C               MANU001,MANU005          ABC,DEF
```

Please give some better way to achieve this. The table contains 1 lakh records.

Comment: This kind of work is normally not done in SQL, but rather in the client code or reporting tools that calls into Sql Server.

Comment: ok.i will ask a new question.

Comment: Please also use **internationally recognized** units of measure - e.g. thousands, millions, billions - so that everyone understand how many rows you're talking about .....

Comment: one millions records

Comment: 1 lakh is not 1 million, it's 100 000.

Comment: correct.In production environment we are having 1 million records so some performance issue is coming